# Multiple Sessions in AWS Lex

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lex

Is it possible to have multiple sessions running parallel to a single **AWS Lex bot**? I have a chatbot application with two intents: *Order Pizza* and *Book Ticket* in a single bot. A user gives the first query to **book a ticket** and simultaneously different user queries about **ordering pizza** from a different machine. How to track both the requests as separate sessions in Lex.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in this [aws docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/lambda-input-response-format.html)

you can see `"userId" attributes` in `Input Event Format`

userId allocated by session(what you mean).

I heard it can be `slack id` or `user account property` (maybe)

so we can track by this `userId`

parallel processing is will supported by aws.

you just code `lambda or something` to hook function with `userId`.